# font awesome in ternary if does not render in angular

Tags: angular

Base on a variable I want to show a text with and fontawsome icon
but the icon doesn't render correctly and it just show code which is related to it.

```
<span> {{ isEditablePropertyworkLogSumTimes == true ? 'edit' : <i _ngcontent-c25="" class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i> }} </span>
```

the result is like this:

> {{ isEditablePropertyworkLogSumTimes == true
> ? 'edit' :  }} 
> [image]

Comment: Apart from my answer, also note that you don't need to check if a boolean is equal to `true`, since itself is a boolean. And when you do, try to make it a habit of using triple equals: `===`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Structural Directive : *ngIf

You shouldn't write html inside the ternary.

Try using the *ngIf structural directive instead.

```html
<span *ngIf="isEditablePropertyworkLogSumTimes; else other" > edit </span>

<ng-template #other>
    <i _ngcontent-c25="" class="fa fa-plus fa-fw"></i>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: I did the same. I think ternary if just works for texts correctly.